# Regular expression to split a string but consider multi-digit escape sequences

Tags: regex, escaping

I could need some help on the following problem with regular expressions and would appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

I have to split a string by another string, let me call it *separator*. However, if an escape sequence preceeds *separatorString*, the string should not be split at this point. The escape sequence is also a string, let me call it *escapeSequence*.

Maybe it is better to start with some examples

> ```
> separatorString = "§§";
>
> escapeSequence = "###";
>
> inputString = "Part1§§Part2" ==> Desired output: "Part1", "Part2"
> inputString = "Part1§§Part2§§ThisIs###§§AllPart3" ==> Desired output: "Part1", "Part2", "ThisIs###§§AllPart3"
> ```

Searching stackoverflow, I found [Splitting a string that has escape sequence using regular expression in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870415/splitting-a-string-that-has-escape-sequence-using-regular-expression-in-java) and came up with the regular expression

`"(?<!(###))§§"`.

This is basically saying, match if you find "§§", unless it is preceeded by "###".

This works fine with Regex.Split for the examples above, however, if inputString is `"Part1###§§§§Part2"` I receive `"Part1###§", "§Part2"` instead of `"Part1###§§", "Part2"`.

I understand why, as the second "§" gives a match, because the proceeding chars are "##§" and not "###". I tried several hours to modify the regex, but the result got only worse. Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the things that appear between the separators, *tokens*.  Your regex needs to stipulate what the beginning and end of a token looks like.

In the absence of any stipulation, in other words, using the regex you have now, the regex engine is happy to say that the first token is `Part1###§` and the second is `§Part2`.

The syntax you used, `(?<!foo)` , is called a *zero-width negative look-behind assertion*. In other words, it looks behind the current match, and makes an assertion that it must match *foo*. Zero-width just indicates that the assertion does not advance the pointer or cursor in the subject string when the assertion is evaluated.

If you require that a new token start with something specific (say, an alphanumeric character), you can specify that with a *zero-width positive lookahead assertion*. It's similar to your lookbehind, but it says "the next bit has to match the following pattern", again without advancing the cursor or pointer.

To use it, put `(?=[A-Z])` following the `§§`.  The entire regex for the separator is then
`(?<!###)§§(?=[A-z])`.

This would  assert that the character following a separator sequence needs to be an uppercase alpha, while the characters preceding the separator sequence must not be ###. In your  example, it would force the match on the `§§` separator to be the pair of chars before `Part2`.  Then you would get `Part1###§§` and `Part2` as the tokens, or group captures.

If you want to stipulate what a token is in the negative - in other words to stipulate the a token begins with anything *except* a certain pattern, you can use a negative lookahead assertion.  The syntax for this is `(?!foo)`.  It works just as you would expect - like your negative lookbehind, only looking forward.

The [regular-expressions.info website](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) has good explanations for all things regex, including [for the lookahead and lookbehind constructs](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

ps: it's "Hello All", not "Hello Together".

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the quick answer and the explanation provided. Your answer might do the trick, although I am not quite sure if it cope with something like that: "Part1###§§§§§§". I might need a result like this "Part1###§§, "", "". However I will need some days to come back to the question, but I will. Bye all ;)

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "cope with". You may want to have $$ be part of the prior token, or you may want $$$$ to denote an empty token. The suggestion I made stipulates that a tokens starts with an uppercase alphanumeric. If you have a different stipulation, then you'll have to use a different regex assertion.

Comment: the problem with `(?<!###)§§` is it will match the last two characters in `###§§§`. It's more solid to use something like `(###§§|.)*`. Or, if you might be escaping other characters with `###`, you could use `(###.{2}|.)*`.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing the opposite: Instead of splitting the string at the separators match non-separator parts and separator parts:

```
/(?:[^§#]|§[^§#]|#(?:[^#]|#(?:[^#]|#§§)))+|§§/
```

Then you just have to remove every matched separator part to get the non-separator parts.

Comment: Thanks to you too, Gumbo. As mentioned above, I will try your solution and give feedback in a few days.