# How can I use javascript split method using escape character?

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to split a string in js with some exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329972/how-to-split-a-string-in-js-with-some-exceptions)

For example if the string is:

```
abc&def&ghi\&klm&nop
```

Required output is array of string

```
['abc', 'def', 'ghi\&klm', 'nop]
```

Please suggest me the simplest solution.

Comment: Although this answer applies to Java, it does tackle the same issue, and shouldn't be difficult to translate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870415/splitting-a-string-that-has-escape-sequence-using-regular-expression-in-java

Comment: @cheeseweasel unfortunately, as js does not implement "negative lookbehind", it will be not that easy to translate. ;)

Comment: some helpful reading: [Mimicking Lookbehind in JavaScript](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript)

Comment: @Yoshi, thanks, I was just looking into it and found that out myself. At least there have been some interesting workarounds offered! :)

Comment: Note for googlers: the duplicate question doesn't provide a definitive answer to this. Since javascript re dialect lacks lookbehinds, the javascript way to split a string with escaped delimiters is to use `match(\\.|[^delim])`, rather than `split`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 12):

You need [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
 "abc&def&ghi\\&klm&nop".match(/(\\.|[^&])+/g)
 # ["abc", "def", "ghi\&klm", "nop"]
```

I'm assuming that your string comes from an external source and is not a javascript literal.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution in JavaScript:

```
var str = 'abc&def&ghi\\&klm&nop',
str.match(/([^\\\][^&]|\\&)+/g); //['abc', 'def', 'ghi\&klm', 'nop]
```

It uses `match` to match all characters which are `([not \ and &] or [\ and &])`.

Answer (score 2):

```
  var str = "abc&def&ghi\\&klm&nop";
  var test = str.replace(/([^\\])&/g, '$1\u000B').split('\u000B');
```

You need to replace \& with double slashes

[how to split a string in js with some exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329972/how-to-split-a-string-in-js-with-some-exceptions)

test will contain the array you need

Answer (score 1):

You can do with only oldschool indexOf:

```
var s = 'abc&def&ghi\\&klm&nop',
    lastIndex = 0,
    prevIndex = -1,
    result = [];
while ((lastIndex = s.indexOf('&', lastIndex+1)) > -1) {
    if (s[lastIndex-1] != '\\') {
        result.push(s.substring(prevIndex+1, lastIndex));
        prevIndex = lastIndex;
    }
}
result.push(s.substring(prevIndex+1));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -7):

try this :

```
var v = "abc&def&ghi\&klm&nop";
var s = v.split("&");
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
    console.log(s[i]);
```