# Java Regular Expression that tokenizes ignoring escaped characters

Tags: java, regex, tokenize

Consider a test string like

```
Irrelevant start|group 1|group 2 with \| escaped|group 3|group 4|Irrelevant end
```

How can this be parsed using a single Java regex, to extract all the groups separated by the bar (|), while ignoring the escaped bar (\|) in the middle, as well as the irrelevant start and end parts (which do not contain a bar)?

One issue with look behind assertion, which has been suggested in an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870415/splitting-a-string-that-has-escape-sequence-using-regular-expression-in-java), is that, in `Java` it does not allow variable length strings and the groups mentioned above have no predefined

Comment: Don't use regex for this. Please don't. Use a CSV parsing library like the excellent OpenCSV.

Comment: That is a very good idea, which I have also considered. Even faster, is to read the string character by character and split on the fly. This is what I am currently doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `split`. We want to split on a `|` that is not preceeded by a `\`. We have to escape `|` in our regex to match `|` instead of using it as `or`. To match a literal `\` in our regex (in the negative look behind), we need `\\\\`.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Irrelevant start|group 1|group 2 with \\| escaped|group 3|group 4|Irrelevant end";
        System.out.println(str);

        String[] arr = str.split("(?<!\\\\)\\|");

        String[] new_arr = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, arr.length - 1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new_arr));

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Irrelevant start|group 1|group 2 with \| escaped|group 3|group 4|Irrelevant end
[Irrelevant start, group 1, group 2 with \| escaped, group 3, group 4, Irrelevant end]
[group 1, group 2 with \| escaped, group 3, group 4]
```

---

For a simple example of the negative look behind, let's just look at `(?<!a)b`. This matches a `b` that is not preceded by an `a`. In our case, we want to match a literal `\` instead of an `a`, and `|` instead of a `b`, which is why we need all the `\`. There are lots of resources for look arounds, but [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is one if you want further reading.

---

Also, Boris the Spider pointed out that this is fragile and there are cases where it won't work. Similarly to how you shouldn't parse XML with a regex, CSV formats should generally be used with a parsing library.

Comment: And what about a pipe preceded by an escaped backslash? And what if that backslash is also escaped? This is not a task for regex unless the aim to create fragile code.

Comment: The bit you left out is that you're using negative lookbehind.

Comment: Boris, I agree it is fragile. David, I added some more detail about the negative lookbehind. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: As I mentioned above, the fastest way is probably reading the whole string one character at a time and splitting on the fly. This is the approach I am following (pending the use of a working regex), but thanks everyone (and +1) for the answers and the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to Matt's answer that I think it's a very good idea, if you are still interested in the regex you can use this one:

```
([\w ]+(\\\|[\w ]+)?)
```

Here you can check a working example:

http://regex101.com/r/hK3fD3/1

As you can see every 1st group for every match contains the relevant content, and you can discard the first and last match.

Hope to help