# Are there other ways to get a List from a String other than splitting it?

Tags: java

There is a string which is a separated string : `item_1|item_2|item_3` , in this example the separating symbol is `|`.

My boss does not like the `split` method to get the different parts of the string: he thinks there is risk about it, but he is not very sure what is the risk. So are there other ways to get a `List` from a separated String?

Comment: Split it manually, using `indexOf` and `subString` ... messing, but it works. I'd be more curious of the "supposed risk".  If they can't identify it, then what's the issue

Comment: What a bizarre thing to not like...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: what 'risk' is there that wouldn't be there otherwise? that | might be used in one of the elements? do you think that wouldn't mess with any other way to do it as well?

Comment: The duplicate contains several ways to split a String (also `#split(..)`, but you don't need to use that answer if you don't like it).

Comment: We need to know a bit more about the format. Can the items contain |, and if so, how is that escaped? (That is, how would a human know that the pipe belongs to the item, and is not a delimiter?)

Comment: @yshavit I think you are guessing my boss' fear ; so how to escape the `|` if it belongs to the item ?

Comment: how about: make sure you get a separator that will never be used in one of the elements.

Comment: it was admitted by our customer that the separator is `|`

Comment: Are you allowed to use floating point numbers where you work? Loads of risks there...

Comment: If you must use an alternative to split, you must also figure out why you should not use split, otherwise any alternatives could have exactly the same issue as split (especially if you just re-implement split yourself.). Try to figure out if you have some bizarre csv like format, where you have 3 items in the line: `item_1|"item|2"|item_3` where the 2. item is enclosed in quotes and therefore the `|` inside it is not a delimiter. Or if your format allows traditional escaping such that `item_1|item\|2|item_3`    is also 3 items and the `|` in `\|` is not a delimiter.

Comment: I mean...talk with your boss..seriously. There is absolutely no "less - risky" way to do this, don't mind about the method that is being used

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870415/splitting-a-string-that-has-escape-sequence-using-regular-expression-in-java

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SplitUsingAnotherMethodBecauseBossLikesWastingEveryonesTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(split("Why would anyone want to write their own String split function in Java?", ' '));
        System.out.println(split("The|Split|Method|Is|Way|More|Flexible||", '|'));
    }

    private static List<String> split(String input, char delimiter) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        int idx = 0;
        int next;

        do {
            next = input.indexOf(delimiter, idx);

            if (next > -1) {
                result.add(input.substring(idx, next));
                idx = next + 1;
            }
        } while(next > -1);

        result.add(input.substring(idx));

        return result;
    }
}
```

Outputs...

```
[Why, would, anyone, want, to, write, their, own, String, split, function, in, Java?]
[The, Split, Method, Is, Way, More, Flexible, , ]
```

Comment: because maybe, just maybe: "why|wou|d|anyone|do|this" would also be a valid input

should that give wou|d, or wou and d ?

Comment: "Why would anyone want to write their own String split function in Java?" Presumably because the standard string split semantics aren't quite what they want -- which makes it not very useful to implement a method with those same semantics. :)

Comment: Then we could call it "cutTheString". No matter what, no matter how, splitting is what it will do. Like saying, I want to add the values from these two integers, but I don't like "add" semantics. p.s, the example string is wonderful, and self declarative indeed

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate over all the `char`s in the string and then use `substring()` to select the different sub strings:

```
public static List<String> split(String input, char delimiter) {
    List<String> output = new LinkedList<>();
    int lastIndex = 0;
    boolean doubleQuote = false;
    boolean singleQuoteFound = false;
    for (int i = 0, current, last = 0, length = input.length(); i < length; i++) {
        current = input.charAt(i);
        if (last != '\\') {
            if (current == '"') {
                doubleQuote = !doubleQuote;
            } else if (current == '\'') {
                singleQuoteFound = !singleQuoteFound;
            } else if (current == delimiter && !doubleQuote && !singleQuoteFound) {
                output.add(input.substring(lastIndex, i));
                lastIndex = i + 1;
            }
        }
        last = current;
    }
    output.add(input.substring(lastIndex));
    return output;
}
```

This is a very crude approach, but from my testing it should take care of escaped delimiters, delimiters in single `'` and/or double `"` -quotes.

Can be called like this:

```
List<String> splitted = split("Hello|World|"No|split|here"|\|Was escaped|'Some|test'", '|');
```

Prints:

```
[Hello, World, "No|split|here", \|Was escaped, 'Some|test']
```

Comment: ok, and how would that solve the puzzle of the delimiter also being able to be part of an element?

Comment: @Stultuske Updated my answer with a working split method, which takes slashes, and quotes into account

Answer (score -1):

> When we use split string, it internally creates Patterns object which overhead but that is  only true for before Java 7 version only, In Java 7/8 it use index of 
>   since java 7 it wont have any overhead of the regular expression engine.However, if you do pass a more complex expression, it reverts to compiling a new pattern and here the behavior should be the same as that on Java 6
>   you can use pre compiled pattern and split the string.

```
public class MyClass {
static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\|");
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "item_1|item_2|item_3";
    Stream<String> streamsName = pattern.splitAsStream(str);
    streamsName.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

}